# Including '+' symbol into a data extension using a smarte capture form and AMPscript in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am attempting to include a value in a cloud data extension using a  smart capture form and AMPscript. The value is a Hashed ID which is included in the email using AMPScript.'%%=v(QueryParameter('Id'))=%%' as value in the form field.

The solution works fine except for when the hashed ID includes a '+'symbol. In the data extension the + is transefered in a ' ' or enter.

e.g.:

0V7R3CB8xcHPdM/OQCyEZTvhDU+dEeKowSU=

turns into:

0V7R3CB8xcHPdM/OQCyEZTvhDU dEeKowSU=

Is there a way to include the full hashed ID in the data extension using this solution? I have tried putting the hashed ID between "'which did not work.

Comment: I had the same problem last week. I used SQL to replace ' ' with '+'

Comment: Thank you for your input. Did you experience this with any other characters or was it only the '+'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is that it is being [URL encoded](https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/ref_urlencode.asp), in which '+' is equal to ' ' (same as '%20').

I would look at utilizing [URLENCODE()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/urlencode.htm) function (Not recommended, but easiest to implement. May cause issues as encoding is automatic) or a [replacelist()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ReplaceList.htm) function to change the spaces back to plus signs (my recommendations as it is fully customizable) when pulling in the email.

I say replacelist() instead of [replace()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Replace.htm) as replace() will only affect the first match, where replacelist() will affect every match.

example of code on Email:

`%%=ReplaceList(QueryParameter('id'), "+", " ")=%%`

Comment: Thank you for you quick answer. Where would you place the replacelist() function typically? Can I include it in the %%=v(QueryParameter('Id'))=%% function?

Comment: In the email call - I have added context and a sample in my answer

Comment: Brilliant! That is the solution. Thank you for your help.